# Multi-level modeling as a statistical criterion

Tags: p-value, multilevel-analysis, ab-test

I found Doordashe's [article](https://doordash.engineering/2019/02/20/experiment-rigor-for-switchback-experiment-analysis/) about conducting switchback experiments. In their article they use multi-level modeling instead of statistical criterions, which are usually used in A/B testing. They thoroughly describe the foundation behind the model, but unfortunately the do not explain how to gain p-value from this model.

Now I know that usuall when Linear regression is used as a criterion for A/B test, we consider slope coefficient as p-value. But what to do in this case and how to reject hyposesis? Also i would quite appreciate a python implementation on this matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such hierarchical model is an extension of linear regression, I would usually call it a [mixed model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model) but terminology differs. Computation is much more involved - you wouldn't be doing this by hand - but interpretation (of the marginal model) is no different than an ordinary linear regression. A quick search reveals that [`statsmodels`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/mixed_linear.html) is able to do this in Python, other suggestion seem to be calling R (`lmer`, `lme4`) from within Python.